# Convert WGS84 lat/long to GGRS87

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx

Hello I am using `GMapsFX` for my JavaFX application. I am getting longtitude and latitute from `Google Maps` with the API but I would like to get `GGRS87` also.

In Greek it is called `EGSA87`. Ι have searched for that and found nothing so far. There might be a solution on the libraries of `Geotools` or `proj4j` but I don't have very good knowledge of java and especially I can't find the solutions in so big libraries like those.

I have found many sites to make calculations but how can I make a mathematical calculation myself? Or even a library to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GDAL library for it, but its setup is actually quite complicated. You would have to install GDAL on your system (it is in Debian packages) and then build the Java JNI bindings for it [1]. [2] is also quite useful in getting it to work.

Then, you could use the Java GDAL library:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and do something like:

```java
final SpatialReference source = new SpatialReference();
source.ImportFromEPSG(4326); // EPSG code for WGS84, see www.epsg.io
final SpatialReference target = new SpatialReference();
target.ImportFromEPSG(4121); // EPSG code for GGRS87, see www.epsg.io
this.coordinateTransform = CoordinateTransformation.CreateCoordinateTransformation(source, target);
final Geometry geometry = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(String.format("POINT (%f %f)", longitude, latitude));
geometry.Transform(coordinateTransform);
final double ggrsX = geometry.GetX();
final double ggrsY = geometry.GetY();
```

- [1] https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJavaBuildInstructionsUnix
- [2] http://geoexamples.blogspot.com/2012/05/running-gdal-java.html

Comment: hello sir may i ask if this is compatitible with java desktop application?Because i believe the first text area reminds me of android application

Comment: Yes, it is. The first snippet is a [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) dependency declaration. If you are not using Maven, you just need to download the GDAL jar file and make sure it is available on the classpath when running the application.